# Factory Restore Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, reset

**Hello,**

So recently I dual-booted my Windows system with Ubuntu, then I decided remove Windows and install Ubuntu 14.04.

Before that, I'm using Windows 7 and upgraded to Windows 8. I have a Toshiba laptop, which is by pressing 0 when booting will lead you into Factory Restore.

In Ubuntu installation options, I choose **Replace Windows 7 With Ubuntu**, then all my Windows files removed.

Today, I decided to go back to Windows 7 by using the Factory Restore, but when I pressed 0 button, it boot straight to Ubuntu/Grub. I have no idea, is my Factory Restore partition got wiped out by Ubuntu installation?

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this question: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on). If you chose to, the installer would of wiped the entire disk and installed Ubuntu - likely including any recovery partitions. You will have to install Windows from a disk ([this](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) may of help there) - if the computer came pre-installed you should be able to use the licence sticker attached to the computer.

Comment: if you do not have a restore disk/usb or partition you are going to need to contact Toshiba for a restore usb/disk.